# ElasticSearch Shield : action [indices:admin/get] is unauthorized for user

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elastic Search 2.0.0 and shield 2.0 Beta version 2 for authentication and authorization (Field level authorization). LDAP Authentication is enabled in ElasticSearch.yml config file and authentication is working fine. Though I have defined the roles and privileges in Roles.yml file, it is throwing **'action [indices:data/read/search] is unauthorized for user'** error while trying to read the data from the elastic search index.

Code snippet provided in the roles.yml file:

```
AccessName:
  indices:
    'IndexA':
      privileges: 'indices:data/read/search'
      fields:
        - FieldA
        - FieldB
```

Any help is appreciated!!!! With Many hearty thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show what query you're running which triggers this error?

Comment: Using postman (Google chrome app), I am trying to fetch the data from the index. Query used is: **localhost:9200/indexA/_search?**

Answer (score 0):

Watch the casing! According to your comment, you're querying `indexA`, yet your configuration references `IndexA`. Fix your roles.yml config like this and try again:

```
AccessName:
  indices:
    'indexA':        <----- initial lowercase initial
      privileges: 'indices:data/read/search'
      fields:
        - FieldA
        - FieldB
```

Comment: Hi Val, I had changed it to lowercase but still I am facing the same issue.

Comment: And you're certain that the user you're using does have the correct role, i.e. `AccessName`?

Comment: Also why does your title mention another error, i.e. `indices:admin/get`?

Comment: Hi Val, that user have correct role and we are facing error in privileges , 'indices:data/read/search' or action [indices:admin/get] is unauthorized for user.

Comment: Hi Val, Please find below the scripts that we are using. **role_mapping.yml** ReadFullAccess:
  - "CN={0},OU=Groups,DC=dir,DC=svc,DC=*****,DC=com"  **roles.yml**

ReadFullAccess:
  indices:
    'indexA':
      privileges: 'indices:admin/get'
      fields:
        - fieldA
        - fieldB